Approximation of Dirac-Measure possible?
Let $A,B$ be two countable sets and $f:A\to B$ injective. One can then prove that
\begin{equation}
1_{b\in\operatorname{im}(f)} = 1_{\exists!a\in A\:: \:f(a)=b} = \sum_{a\in A} 1_{f(a)=b}.
\end{equation}
I used indicator functions here.
Question I am looking for a similar formula in the case where $A,B$ are uncountable. E.g. let $A=B=[0,1]$ and $f:A\to B$ injective. Morally, I wish for something like
\begin{equation}
1_{b\in\operatorname{im}(f)} \approx \int_A 1_{f(a)=b}\: da,
\end{equation}
but of course the integral on the right is $0$, so it won't work like this. I am thinking of using some sort of approximation to the Dirac-Measure, s.t. the limit is equal to $1_{b\in\operatorname{im}(f)}$ and the elements of the sequence resemble an integral like $\int_A\dots da$. I know that often people speak of 'delta-functions' in such cases but as far as I know that symbolism isn't really well defined.
Any help is appreciated.

What keeps you from just decomposing it into a sum as well? I.e. $1_{im f} = \sum_{a\in A} 1_{f(a)}$. Then both sides are equal since $1_{im f}(x) = 1$ iff $x\in im f$ iff $x=f(a)$ for exactly one $a\in A$, so that the sum on the right has exactly one term equal to $1$ and the others equal to $0$ due to injectivity (keyword summable families). Am I missing something or did I misunderstand you?

Alternatively you could probably try to understand $\int_A 1_{f(a)} d\mu(a)$ with respect to the counting measure as a Bochner integral on some suitable Banach space of functions but that seems a bit overkill and basically just encapsules the notion of summable families
